# ¿Como puedo instalar la biblioteca GD en Windows 10?

Tags: php, gd

[image: gd]

Me pide este requisito y no tengo ni idea de como instalarlo

Comment: Documenta [fuentes oficiales](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.image.php), este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas.

Comment: si estas usando windows tienes que descargar la libreria.

Comment: Kinslert como descargo la libreria?

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: @Ringoelie fijate del comentario, si no es estas en linux, cual es el sistema operativo que estas usando ? cuando este tipo de cosas sucede es bueno especificar, ya que cuando comenté me eliminaron dos puntos de tu publicación hacia mi calificación.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el archivo `php.ini` en tu carpeta donde tienes PHP. Revisa si `php_gd2.dll` se encuentra en tus extensiones y quita el comentario en `;extension=php_gd2.dll` para habilitarlo. Para quitar el comentario solo remueve el punto y coma.

Si los cambios no se han aplicado reinicia el servidor.

**NOTA**

Puede tambien estar como `;extension=gd2`, es la misma librería.

Comment: En php8 puede estar como extension=gd